# Understanding Paladin Danse's history

Tags: fallout-4

So I've found out that

> Paladin Danse is a synth.

What is his history?

> Where is the human Danse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "human" Danse.  Danse was a Synth designed by the Institute, and most likely had his memories wiped (so he had no idea that he was actually a synth).  What Namikaze's brought up in the comments is possible but so far nothing canonical has been addressed in game.